# dynamic MessageBox using variables (c++)

Tags: c++, messagebox

I want to create a dynamic MessageBox using a char array, but i have some problem with the uType (UINT)..

If you watch my code, i first have a char string with | delimiters and it's parsed into the array "a". Then i convert my char into UINT but i cant get it work, it just doesnt show any messagebox.
Thanks for helping :-)

```
char str[] ="Testing message|Title Message|MB_OK|MB_ICONINFORMATION";
char * pch;
char * a[4];
int i = 0;
pch = strtok (str,"|");
while (pch != NULL)
{
    a[i] = pch;
    pch = strtok (NULL, "|");
    //cout << a[i];
    i++;
}
char test[1000] = "";
strcat_s (test,a[2]);
strcat_s (test,"|");
strcat_s (test,a[3]);

UINT y;
stringstream s;
s << test;
s >> y;


MessageBox(0,a[0],a[1],y);
Sleep(10000);
```

Solution :

```
                        UINT x;
                            if(!strcmp(a[3],"MB_ICONERROR")){
                                x = 0x10;
                            }else if(!strcmp(a[3],"MB_ICONEXCLAMATION")){
                                x = 0x30;
                            }else if(!strcmp(a[3],"MB_ICONINFORMATION")){
                                x = 0x40;
                            }else if(!strcmp(a[3],"MB_ICONQUESTION")){
                                x = 0x20;
                            }
                            if(!strcmp(a[2],"MB_OK")){
                                x = x + 0;
                            }else if(!strcmp(a[2],"MB_OKCANCEL")){
                                x = x + 1;
                            }else if(!strcmp(a[2],"MB_YESNO")){
                                x = x + 4;
                            }else if(!strcmp(a[2],"MB_YESNOCANCEL")){
                                x = x + 3;
                            }else if(!strcmp(a[2],"MB_RETRYCANCEL")){
                                x = x + 5;
                            }else if(!strcmp(a[2],"MB_ABORTRETRYIGNORE")){
                                x = x + 2;
                            }
                            MessageBox(0, a[0], a[1], x);
```

Comment: This is horrible C++ code, sorry. Use proper C++ functionality, not legacy C functions.

Comment: I would be interested to see how you do that properly ? I'm new to c++

Comment: Mainly, use `std::string` instead of `char const*` (and especially no fixed buffers!), then you don’t need to use `strcmp` (instead, you can use `==`) or `strcat` (which is prone to overflow; use `+` or `+=`) and use `std::find` and similar algorithms instead of `strtok`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
MB_OK|MB_ICONINFORMATION
```

Those are 'enumerations' and not actual strings. 
In your program (outside of the string), they would get replaced by numbers.
What you're doing, is trying to convert a plain string into a number, which obviously doesn't yield the expected result, since the system doesn't recognize the enumerations any more then.

I suggest using some sort of mask, or inputting the 'plain' value into the string.
For your example, that's 0x40, as can be seen [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645505%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

So, try to use a string like this:

```
char str[] ="Testing message|Title Message|0x40";
```

And make sure, that the last element is treated as Integer, and not as 'string'.

Comment: Glad to know, that I was able to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

According to [this page](http://goo.gl/N2ecA) MB_OK and MB_ICONINFORMATION are #defines, so if you were to do something like:

```
y = MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION;
```

you'd get the value you want into the y variable.

However, you have a string with the *names* of the #defines in it.  Neither stringstream nor any other simple thing I can think of will convert them to the numbers you need.

UPDATE:

You added the following if/else ladder to the question as your solution:

```
UINT x;
if(!strcmp(a[3],"MB_ICONERROR")){
    x = 0x10;
} else if(!strcmp(a[3],"MB_ICONEXCLAMATION")){
    x = 0x30;
...
```

If you're going to do that, then replace the literal constants with the #defines and it should be cleaner and it won't have the possibility get out of date or have errors.  (I realize that as windows constants these probably don't change often, but it's better practice this way.)

This would look like this:

```
UINT x;
if(!strcmp(a[3],"MB_ICONERROR")){
    x = MB_ICONERROR;
} else if(!strcmp(a[3],"MB_ICONEXCLAMATION")){
    x = MB_ICONEXCLAMATION;
...
```

Comment: Not no way, just no simple simple way.  I updated my answer to reflect a way of making the compiler do the conversion for you in the if/else ladder so that at least you don't have bare numbers in the code like that.